# Warning pandas, 2 loopings!

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pessoal estou com problema neste looping, por que é uma situação que nao consigo resolver com `np.where`, por que tem que correr o `DataFrame` para achar o valor do ganho ou da perda apartir de outra condição, qual vier primeiro.

Está funcionando mas fico recebendo este warning:

> ```
> C:\Users\Jair\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:14: SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> ```

```py
def estrategia_2_alta(candles):

    for i in range(1,len(candles)):
        if candles['Twintower'][i]== 1:
            loop2 = i
            for twin in range(loop2+1, len(candles)):
                if candles['askclose'][twin]>=candles['Gain'][i]:

                    candles['Resultado'][i] = candles['Tamanho_Twin'][i]*GainC
                    break

                elif candles['askhigh'][twin]>=candles['Gain'][i]:

                    candles['Resultado'][i] = candles['Tamanho_Twin'][i]*GainC
                    break

                elif candles['askclose'][twin]<=candles['Loss'][i]:
                    candles['Resultado'][i] = candles['Tamanho_Twin'][i]*(-StopC)
                    break

                elif candles['asklow'][twin]<=candles['Loss'][i]:

                    candles['Resultado'][i] = candles['Tamanho_Twin'][i]*(-StopC)
                    break
```

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

Esse problema está acontecendo por causa da sua atribuição candles['Twintower'][i]. O pandas não "gosta" muito dessa atribuição. Experimente fazer:

```
candles[i, 'Twintower']
```

Esse artigo explica um pouco o iloc e o loc.
https://medium.com/horadecodar/data-science-tips-02-como-usar-loc-e-iloc-no-pandas-fab58e214d87

Ah..
Saiba que np.where também aceita condições dentro.

```
np.where(<condição>, <se verdadeiro> , np.where(<condição>, <se verdadeiro>, <se falso>))
```