# Pandas iterrows, como fazer o segundo looping usando o index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
for index, row in candles.iterrows():
    if (row['Twintower'] == 1):
```

Eu gostaria de fazer um segundo looping a partir do momento que ele achar esta condição, ou seja deste index para baixo, ou row para baixo, tentei varias opções

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-e34b05ba34a8> in <module>
      1 for index, row in candles.iterrows():
      2     if (row['Twintower'] == 1):
----> 3         for row in range(index, candles):
      4             print(1)

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: @jsbueno, tem como vc ajudar, eu realmente nao consigo fazer o segundo looping pegando apartir do momento que ele acha a segunda condicao, tentei usar range(row, candles) mas nao deu

Answer (score 1):

Você não parece precisar de um segundo loop aí - você continua precisando percorrer todas as linhas (rows) do dataframe uma única vez, embora com dois propósitos diferentes: você quer percorrer as primeiras linhas até achar o momento em que sua condiçao é verdadeira pela primeira vez, e a partir daí percorrer as demais linhas, executando alguma outra ação.

Você até poderia sim, fazer em duas etapas - a primeira apenas para anotar o valor de "index" quando a sua condição é verdadeira, e outra, tendo esse valor, daí pra baixo. É o que você está tentando fazer, e a eficiência do programa seria a mesma, afinal, cada linha seria percorrida uma única vez. No entanto, a função `iterrows` não aceita uma linha de início.  (E por causa disso você tentou usar um `range` para obter um número de índice da linha - isso está errado em vários níveis. E o nível em que dá erro é que o eixo de índice do seu dataframe não é um número inteiro, e sim um objeto "TimeStamp" do Pandas - por isso o erro que você tem ao chamar o range).

Então, já que o iterrows não permite um índice de início, uma forma legal de trabalhar aí é ter uma outra variável, que indique se você já atingiu seu ponto de interesse ou não - e só a partir daí executar as ações que seriam executadas no seu segundo loop. A chave para isso é pular a execução de uma parte do bloco do loop com o uso do comando `continue`: ele simplesmente pula para a próxima execução do loop.

Então, o que você está tentando fazer pode ser escrito como:

```
region_of_interest = False
for index, row in candles.iterrows():
    if (row['Twintower'] == 1):
        region_of_interest = True
    if not region_of_interest:
        # Até que a condição de cima seja verdadeira a primeira vez,
        # retona ao inicio do loop aqui
        continue

    # Aqui vai o código que você estava qurendo colocar
    # no "segundo loop".
    ...
```

Se você realmente quiser "recortar" o dataframe  a partir do índice onde a condição é verdadeira, isso também é possível - nesse caso, talvez o mais recomendado seja criar uma nova cópia do dataframe só com as linhas de interesse, e aí, repetir o `iterrows`:

```
for row_number, (index, row) in enumerate(candles.iterrows()):
    if (row['Twintower'] == 1):
        # Encerra este loop nesse ponto
        break
else:
   # Else do comando for - este bloco só é executado se o comando
   # break acima não acontecer nunca.
   raise ValueError("O dataframe não tem uma linha onde Twintower == 1")

# O atributo ".loc" do dataframe retorna um objeto que tem a cópia
# dos dados do dataframe, mas é endereçavel com a sintaxe de "[]"
# com números do Python (e se você recortar uma fatia desse objeto,
# tem  um novo dataframe)
candles2 = candles.loc[row_number:]

for index, row in candles2.iterrows():
    # aqui é seu segundo loop, somente na região de interesse.
    ...
```

Comment: Desde já agradeço a esclarecedora resposta. Eu estou tentando achar solução, para isto aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352660/warning-pandas-2-loopings/352661?noredirect=1#comment707555_352661      Não sei por que cargas dagua este looping demora infinito para rodar e ainda tomo warning do ipython, então esotu tentando uma outra forma de escrever o codigo, que na minha opnião estava eficiente.

Comment: O seu código inicial tentava colocar um loop dentro do outro. (dica - o substantivo é "loop", ou "laço" em português - "looping" é incorreto) -  se em algum ponto o que você estava tentando fazer antes não deu um erro direto, você pode estar tentanto percorrer _todas_ as linhas para _cada_ linha do seu dataframe.

Comment: So uma coisa ja tentei candles.iloc e candles.loc[i, 'askclose'], continua o warning e a demora para rodar o loop, eu queria escrever de uma forma mais 'pythonica'

Comment: eu coloquei duas formas bem pythonicas aí em cima.

Comment: mas eu tenho um dataframe de 10mil linhas, com 326 ['Twintower'] == 1, entao para cada vez que ele achar um candles['twintower'] == 1, eu quero que ele encontre dali para baixo, ou o stop loss ou o gain, mas depois ele volta e continua procurando novamente ['Twintower']==1, no link que postei tem o loop todo

Comment: for row_number, index, row in enumerate(candles.iterrows()):
    if (row['Twintower'] == 1): esta dando esta mensagem : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) @jsbueno

Comment: Faltou um parenteses. Vou arrumar lá.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver com o mesmo looping anterior porem ao inves de ja passar o valor para o dataframe, eu faço uma lista e depois ligo coluna com a função  candles['Resultado'] = estrategia_2_alta(candles), da um pouco de trabalho, vou ter que fazer outra função para redimensionar o dataframe quando a lista tiver um resultado a menos, mas foi a solução que achei, o iterrow nao resolveu meu problema por que nao deu para colocar if e elif ele corre o dataframe inteiro direto.